# Override the cabal version of an LTS

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I have a project that I want to compile with LTS 2, but I'm stuck trying to work around [this well-known bug in OS X 10.11](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2653).

Can I somehow specify a newer version of `Cabal` to use with `ghc-7.8.4`? Note that the project only really compiles with GHC 7.8.*.

Edit:

Really meant `Cabal`, not `cabal-install`.

Edit 2:

Actually, the answer to this question doesn't really solve my concrete problem (compiling `helium`, which requires GHC <= 7.8.4), because the bug is not specific to `Cabal`, but rather to `unix`, which GHC < 7.10 depends upon.

Comment: If there is no other way you could always just drop stack and use plain cabal. It's not ideal, but a good last resort if stack gets stuck.

Comment: I don't think `stack` calls the cabal binary - at least not stack-1.1.2. I would try asking on the [haskell-stack mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/haskell-stack) or compile using a cabal sandbox.

Comment: Are you looking for stack setup --upgrade-cabal?

Comment: `stack setup --upgrade-cabal` might be just what I need, but it errors out due to that same bug.

Comment: OK, I managed to upgrade cabal by disabling and re-enabling the rootless feature (http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/). While that didn't get rid of the original problem (still errors out due to the same bug), I'd say your tip qualifies as the answer to this question, @MichaelSnoyman, so feel free to make an answer off this.

Comment: (That bug seems not only to be inherent to `Cabal`, but also to GHC < 7.10, because of `unix`, so there's that...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in [Michael Snoyman's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824676/override-the-cabal-version-of-an-lts#comment65039487_38824676), there is `stack setup --upgrade-cabal` to do just that. That's it for the answer to this question.

---

In my specific case (XY problem), for that to work I had to do the usual work-around for [that El Capitano related bug](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/2653), which is explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/196226/67442). So I enabled rootless, ran the upgrade command and re-enabled rootless.

To no avail I'm afraid: The bug is specific to `unix < 2.7.1.0`, which GHC 7.8.4 also depends on. So even after upgrading cabal, I can't compile anything in lts-2 unless I disable rootless, which is pretty annoying.

Actually it's kinda depressing that [the GHC folks decided not to file a new minor release](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/blog/weekly20150721#MacOSXElCapitansupport) with the updated `unix` package. This means that no realistic/recent OS X configuration can build anything which involves GHC < 7.10.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is related not just to `Cabal` library version (btw, stack doesn't use or need `cabal-install`), but also to GHC version. Stack's FAQ mentions an [item about this error](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/faq/#why-do-i-get-a-usrbinar-permission-denied-error), but I think it didn't help for me and I just upgraded to 7.10.2 at the time.

Comment: I'm trying to compile the `helium` compiler, but only have GHC 7.10 installed globally, which doesn't compile. Installing GHC 7.8 side-by-side would be too much of a hassle (I'd rather not try `helium` then), so I tried to use `stack`, which would obviously fit the bill if not for that bug.

Comment: @SebastianGraf with `stack`, there's no hassle installing GHC 7.10. Just run `stack setup` and it'll install ghc inside `~/.stack`, without polluting your path. Upon next run of `stack build`, it'll figure out to use that GHC even if it's not on your PATH.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But `helium` doesn't build with 7.10, so I either have to use lts-2.22 or install 7.8 manually in a way that doesn't pollute my path.

Comment: @SebastianGraf sorry, I meant 7.8, or 8.0, or whatever is needed. Just do `stack setup --resolver=lts-2.2` or run `stack setup` inside a helium proj with `stack.yaml`. Stack handles multiple GHC's installed side by side inside `~/.stack`

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing right know, but I hit the bug I mentioned in the OP. That's why I wanted to use the same LTS (e.g. 2.22, one with GHC 7.8.4), but with a newer cabal version, because I thought that bug was inherent to `Cabal`. It turns out, that `stack setup --upgrade-cabal` was what I was looking for (see the comments of the OP), but it doesn't help because the bug is in `unix`, which is also used by GHC, I think. Anyway, still could not compile `helium` without going rootless (which helped). Seems like that's the only way to get what I want.

Comment: Regardless, `stack setup --upgrade-cabal` together with going rootless for the time of the installation is the answer to this question. It just doesn't help with the concrete problem I'm facing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recipe for installing ghc-7.8.4 into the directory of your choice:

1. Download the "bindist" from https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_8_4#macosx_x86_64
2. Untar it into a scratch directory
3. Create the destination directory, e.g. `$HOME/my-prefix`.
4. In the scratch directory run:

   ```
   $ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/my-prefix
   $ make install
   ```

Now ghc may be found in `$HOME/my-prefix/bin`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really answer the question I asked and also doesn't help with the concrete problem I'm facing, because the bug is present in `unix < 2.7.1.0`, which both `Cabal` and `ghc` < 7.10 depend upon. The only real workaround is to disable rootless mode, from what I can tell.

Comment: But  you can rebuild the version of unix that you need with this version of ghc.